# MVC Custom Attribute - Client-side Validation - Warning: No message defined for 'field'

Tags: validation, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I tried to create a custom data annotation validation attribute (NameValidationAttribute) in MVC 5 project using VS2013. I was able to successfully add the client side validation and the error message for custom validation is getting displayed as soon as the focus leaves the textbox. However, the standard attributes like [Required] and [Range] validators are now not showing proper error messages, says 'Warning: No message defined for 'field' ' (See below screenshot).

Question:
- Why the standard validation error messages are showing as "Warning: No message defined for UnitsInStock"? What am I missing?

[image]

Below is my custom client validation script:
[image]

I included following scripts in EditProducts page.

[image]

Please note that the error messages for UnitPrice, UnitsInStock and ReorderLevel fields are defined with Range validation attribute (see below).

[image]

FYI, I tried to change the order of the scripts in ProductEdit page but still its showing the same message.

Please advise!

Comment: anyone out there for help?

Comment: I'm seeing similar flash before seemingly the client side code is actually deciding to figure out what to display.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. I had created an MVC attribute called PasswordAttribute, with a client side validator called 'password'.

```
$.validator.addMethod('password', function (value, element, params) {
    ...[validation logic]
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('password');
```

As soon as I added this logic to the solution I got the error you saw on my Password and ConfirmPassword fields. Note that this occurred before the attribute was even used. Simply renaming the client side validator to 'passwordcheck' fixed the issue. I initially thought that the name 'password' possibly clashed with one of the pre-defined validators (cf. [jQuery Validation Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)) but this doesn't appear to be the case. I suspect now that it is a clash with the name or value for some input field attribute. Anyway, the solution was simply to rename the validator.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery unobtrusive need `data-msg` for default validate message. 
This is how to apply dynamic error message from your model to Html

```
  $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requireif", function (options) {
        $('#' + options.element.id).attr("data-msg", options.message);
        // Add rule ...
    });
```

You can change default warning message.

```
 $.validator.addMethod("requireif", function (value, element, pair) {
        // validate logic
        return true/false;
 }, "YOUR DEFAULT MESSAGE HERE");
```

Or

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1, new { Class = "form-control", data_msg = "YOUR DEFAULT MESSAGE HERE" })
```

Or if you can put it directly to your Html like this.

```
<input class="form-control" data-msg="YOUR DEFAULT MESSAGE HERE"/>
```